# iOS Native to Forms navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have been working on an application that uses both forms and native in Xamarin. The app starts with the form and switch to native to open the camera. My problem is once the image is clicked I want to go back to Forms application but I am unable to find enough documentation on it. 
I have tried Navigation.PushAsync in iOS but it doesnt work.

```
var videoConnection = stillImageOutput.ConnectionFromMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
        var sampleBuffer = await stillImageOutput.CaptureStillImageTaskAsync(videoConnection);
        var jpegImage = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.JpegStillToNSData(sampleBuffer);


        var photo = new UIImage(jpegImage);

        byte[] data;

        NSData imageData = photo.AsJPEG();
        data = new byte[imageData.Length];

        EnrollImageDisplay.ImageData = data;
```

Where EnrollImageDisplay is my content page in forms. Not I have to call this page but I am unable to do so. Any solution with this?

**EDIT**: Solved it using Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());

Comment: A Forms app lives within a singular dynamically created ViewController, so if you are opening a new viewcontroller from Forms, you can pass some form-based context to that view controller so you can "pass data back" (a singleton works, or using a iOS notification via Grand Central Dispatch, etc..), and then you will want to close your Camera-based VC and take action as that last Forms' Page is now becomes active, so you can push a new Forms' Page at that point.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have been able to call the page through Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page()); but I am unable to pass the data as shown above  EnrollImageDisplay.ImageData = data; I am fairly new to Xamarin native. Could you please give me an example or a source?

Comment: The camerapage is actually a page renderer from forms.

Comment: I solved it, I was missing system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy. I will edit the answer.